# Spring Data MongoDB vs. native MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I need food for thought.

My project is a ddd-/clean architecture-like project, so i want my domain framework free.
Now I have repositories in my domain with some methods like loadAggregate(...) saveAggregate(...) etc.
And additionally there are query repositories with other data structure to read the data.

Now I need to implement that repositories and I want to use MongoDB.
But I don't know, what is the best strategy.

My Rest-Framework is Spring, so I can use String Data MongoDB. But how can I connect my simple repositories with the spring repositories?

Or I can use MongoDB natively or with KMongo...

Which choice is the best solution to start with?

I hope, my trouble became clear.

Big thx!